# Beginners guide to Inverse Kinematics for biped robots?

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, inverse-kinematics, humanoid

I'm building a LynxMotion Scout biped and believe that [IK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics) are the best way to develop an effective gait.

I'm a mechanical design engineer - I currently have minimal skills / experience with programming, which I am looking to improve.

Does anyone have any suggestions for IK resources for bipeds that would assist my learning / knowledge of IK? (I have already searched online, with little success).

I would really appreciate any pointers or resources you can provide.

Comment: I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read etc.) may be about difficult decisions, & they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation & are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].